# Unit testing assertions in command line applications with Click

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line-arguments

I need to unit test that an assertion is raised in a command line function.

`click` provides functionality to test command line applications, and `unittest` provides functionality to test that assertions are raised. My problem is combining the two.

What I'm testing is similar to the code below. There is a function with a command-line argument and an option that must be specified if that the argument is a certain value. It is similar in spirit to this example:

```
import unittest
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

@click.command()
@click.argument('name')
@click.option('--age')
def hello(name, age):
    if name == 'Peter' and not age:
        raise ValueError('Please specify an age!')
    click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)


class TestClickAssertion(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello_world(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            runner = CliRunner()
            result = runner.invoke(hello, ['Peter'])
            print(result)
```

The issue I have, is that running with unittest in pycharm, I get an `AssertionError: ValueError not raised` but the `print()` command prints `<Result ValueError('Please specify an age!',)>`: which is what I want!

How do I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you experienced, `CliRunner` will not raise exceptions, but will return them in the result object ([documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.Result)).

So instead of using `assertRaises` check that `isinstance(result.exception, ValueError)`.